# Integrating Python into Java - can we call .py files directly?

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to understand Jython. I have some algorithms written in Python that I want to integrate in Java. The Jython docs are very complex for me to understand. All I could get from them is that I can run individual Python statements from Java by embedding them like this:

```
interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.exec("import sys");
        interp.exec("print sys");
```

But I can't embed my giant algorithms like that. I need to run the py scripts. Is there any way to do that? Can I get a hello world example where the `print("hello")` statement is written in a py script file and the output is shown on a Java console?

Comment: Can't you use `PythonInterpreter.execfile()`? See http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#execfile(java.lang.String).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jython its the better option

else you can run python program from the java using the command prompt and collect the output back in java

as eg:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\Users\\Bens\\Desktop\\test.py");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TCPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Hey can you guide me on how to do this on Linux?

Comment: you can use String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", command}; ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands );

if in the case of debian 
you can try  "/bin/bash" instead of "/bin/sh"